# Does an open source project need a news group?

Tags: open-source, newsgroup

I open-sourced a [tool](http://code.google.com/p/revitpythonshell/) I created to scratch an itch. From the downloads for the installer on the project page I can see I'm not the only one interested. About 5 people seem to have upgraded from the previous version. But I know next to nothing about them.

Do I need a news group? A mailing list? Or how would you start to build a (little) community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have webhosting, the simplest to set up is an online forum or bulletin board (e.g. phpBB, vBulletin.)  I used to an open-source tool for Nagios and shamelessly used their mailing lists for support, and people started e-mailing me directly using my e-mail address from my posts.

I see you're hosting on Google - [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/) does newsgroups, so maybe set one of those up for your tool?

Comment: ;) didn't you know Jeff Atwoods mission statement is to kill phpBB?

Comment: I hope he achieves it!  It's a decent application but it does get exploited way too much and way too quickly.

Answer (score 3):

It mainly depend what kind of interaction you want with them.

With such a few people the mailing list or a news group looks the most appropriate.

A forum with such a small number of people is generally not very active. (From other people it may looks like an inactive project).

Comment: Thank you. These are good points.